# How to parse table in HTML file cleanly with R

Tags: html, r, html-table, tidyverse

I have the following HTML file accessible from
here:

https://dpaste.org/oGQG

I tried the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)

html_file <- "my_html_file.html"

html <- xml2::read_html(html_file,
                        encoding = "UTF-8",
                        options = "RECOVER",
                        warn = FALSE, verbose = TRUE)
html_res <- rvest::html_table(html, trim = FALSE)

df <- html_res[[1]]

df %>%
  janitor::clean_names() %>%
  dplyr::select(run_id, s_id, s_number, library, s_name, tissue)
```

The result it gives me is as follow:

```
# A tibble: 26 x 6
   run_id                   s_id       s_number    library       s_name             tissue       
   <chr>                    <chr>      <chr>       <chr>         <chr>              <chr>        
 1 "210510_VH00236_65_AAAJ… "KS_=\r\n… "S1"        "KAPA_HMR"    "01_PaS_6h_0uM_1<… "Cervical MS…
 2 "210510_VH00236_65_AAAJ… "KS_002"   "S2"        "K=\r\nAPA_H… "02_PaS_6h_0uM_2"  "Cervical MS…
 3 "210510_VH00236_65_AAAJ… "KS_003"   "S3"        "KAPA_HMR"    "Cervical MSC"     ""           
 4 "210510_VH00236_65_AAAJ… "KS_004"   "S4=\r\ntd… "KAPA_HMR"    "04_PaS_6h_20uM_1" "Cervica=\r\…
 5 "210510_VH00=\r\n236_65… "KS_005"   "S5"        "KAPA_HMR=\r… "05_PaS_6h_20uM_2" "Cervical MS…
 6 "210510_VH00236_65_AAAJ… "KS_006"   "S6"        "KAPA_HMR"    "06_PaS_6h=\r\n_2… "Cervical MS…
 7 "210510_VH00236_65=\r\n… "KS_008"   "S8"        "KAPA_HMR"    "08_PaS_6h_50uM_2" "Cervical MS…
 8 "210510_VH00236_65_AAAJ… "KS_=\r\n… "S9"        "KAPA_HMR"    "09_PaS_6h_50uM_3… "Cervical MS…
 9 "210510_VH00236_65_AAAJ… "KS_010"   "S10"       "KAPA_HMR"    "10_PaS_24h_0uM_1" "Cervical MS…
10 "210510_VH00236_65_AAA=… "KS_011"   "S11"       "KAPA_HMR"    "11_PaS_24h_0uM_2" "Cervical MS…
# … with 16 more rows
```

Note that it's not cleanly parsed. Some row still contains `=\r\n` in it.
How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: How do we use the HTML file you linked? Can you provide `dput(df)` instead ?

Comment: @RonakShah After you click the link https://dpaste.org/oGQG. You can copy the text with `Copy Snippet` there, and paste to a editor and save as HTML.  I can't use `dput`, coz the output will be too large to put here.

Comment: When I save that snippet and view the HTML, I see some of the errors you want fixed in a browser.  For example, row 3 of the table is missing the `Read` column, with other entries shifted left.  These errors are in the original data, they aren't coming from the parsing by `rvest::html_table`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a start.

Removed all occurrences of `'\r\n'` with `<` and `=` along with `<a>` where `<` is optional and `td>`. The main task is to identify the patterns which are not needed in the data.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  janitor::clean_names() %>%
  dplyr::select(run_id, s_id, s_number, library, s_name, tissue) %>% 
  mutate(across(.fns = ~gsub('[\r\n<=]|<?a>|td>', '', .)))

#  run_id                      s_id   s_number library  s_name           tissue        
#   <chr>                       <chr>  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>            <chr>         
# 1 210510_VH00236_65_AAAJGJ5M5 KS_001 S1       KAPA_HMR 01_PaS_6h_0uM_1/ "Cervical MSC"
# 2 210510_VH00236_65_AAAJGJ5M5 KS_002 S2       KAPA_HMR 02_PaS_6h_0uM_2  "Cervical MSC"
# 3 210510_VH00236_65_AAAJGJ5M5 KS_003 S3       KAPA_HMR Cervical MSC     ""            
# 4 210510_VH00236_65_AAAJGJ5M5 KS_004 S4       KAPA_HMR 04_PaS_6h_20uM_1 "Cervical MSC"
# 5 210510_VH00236_65_AAAJGJ5M5 KS_005 S5       KAPA_HMR 05_PaS_6h_20uM_2 "Cervical MSC"
# 6 210510_VH00236_65_AAAJGJ5M5 KS_006 S6       KAPA_HMR 06_PaS_6h_20uM_3 "Cervical MSC"
# 7 210510_VH00236_65_AAAJGJ5M5 KS_008 S8       KAPA_HMR 08_PaS_6h_50uM_2 "Cervical MSC"
# 8 210510_VH00236_65_AAAJGJ5M5 KS_009 S9       KAPA_HMR 09_PaS_6h_50uM_3 "Cervical MSC"
# 9 210510_VH00236_65_AAAJGJ5M5 KS_010 S10      KAPA_HMR 10_PaS_24h_0uM_1 "Cervical MSC"
#10 210510_VH00236_65_AAAJGJ5M5 KS_011 S11      KAPA_HMR 11_PaS_24h_0uM_2 "Cervical MSC"
# … with 16 more rows
```

Comment: thank you. But on the third row `s_name` value is shifted to the left from tissue. It fails to parse the content. It should contain `03_PaS_6h_0uM_3`.
How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: That does not come from my code. It is already present when you do `df %>%
  janitor::clean_names() %>% dplyr::select(run_id, s_id, s_number, library, s_name, tissue)`

Comment: I understand that. It's a parsing issue  from `rvest::html_table()`  or `xml2::read_html` . So the main question is how to do initial **parse** correctly and cleanly.

Comment: Sorry, it was not clear to me that is what you were looking for from your post. I thought you want to clean the additional texts with `=\r\n` in it.